# Объект "TypesOfWork" не существует или не допустим в этой операции

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TRIGGER trDelWork
On TypesOfWork
for delete
As
set nocount on
declare @ident int
Select @ident =  deleted.TypeOfWorkCode -1 from deleted
DBCC checkident(TypesOfWork, Reseed, @ident)
go
```

Имеется код создания триггера, подчеркивает TypesOfWork и TypeOfWorkCode.

При наведении курсора показывает 'Объект "TypesOfWork" не существует или не допустим в этой операции' и 'недопустимое имя столбца"TypeOfWorkCode"' соответственно. Необходимая таблица и поле в ней существуют.
Подскажите, в чем я допустил ошибку?

Comment: Возможно, вы не выбрали базу данных. Например, у вас текущей БД является master

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможные варианты причин:

1) Вы выбрали не ту базу данных. Перед созданием триггера добавьте следующий код:

```
use [ваша база]

go
```

2) Указанная вами таблица находится не в схеме по умолчанию. В коде создания триггера поменяйте указание на базу:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trDelWork
On [ваша схема].TypesOfWork
```

3) Вы ошиблись в написании имени таблицы. откройте обозреватель объектов, скопируйте название таблицы и замените его в коде создания триггера.

Comment: Первый вариант.
нужно было всего лишь выполнить команду `USE AutoService` перед созданием триггера